# How to predict projectile motion?

Tags: python, math, projectile

I am required to carry out a project work in predicting the trajectory of a moving ball in air moving in two dimensions.

So what are the possible approaches in dealing with it? It'll be helpful if you provide some details. Also, I dont know if this is the correct place to ask such things. But you see, only experts can show a path to follow!

I can do image processing like edge detection and some computer vision like lane detection using hough transforms, tracking some body (but no prediction), face detection, etc.

I attempted to complete this project by using kalman filters but I am stucked and
cant find a way out. So I thought maybe I should look for other approaches.

Comment: This is a simple problem in physics.  It's the first chapter in Newtonian mechanics.  I'd suggest you read it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a site for practical computer programming, so I'll discuss an approach that uses that. Since you provide no details of your own, I also avoid details. If you want more details on this approach you will need edit your question to show more effort of your own, preferably with some code.

This, like many physics problems, could be considered to be a problem in ordinary differential equations with initial values. But like many problems you need to list your assumptions. Let's say the ball is moving near the surface of the earth which is near sea level, in earth's atmosphere, with speeds well below the speed of sound. So the gravitational acceleration, air density, and so on can be considered to be constants. The mass and size of the ball may matter, but let's consider only the mass and wrap up any issues of the size (and shape) of the ball into the air resistance. For a given problem, you can consider the "air resistance factor" also to be constant.

Your initial values are:

1. the location of the ball at the starting time. Since you write "moving in two dimensions" we can make them `x` (horizontal position) and `y` (vertical position) with respect to the ground. They do need to be horizontal and vertical, appropriate for the part of the earth where the ball is.
2. the initial velocity of the ball. This will also have horizontal and vertical components, so we can use the variables `vx` and `vy`.

Then you have four changing variables, `x`, `y`, `vx`, and `vy`. The equations on the ball come from Newton's Laws of Motion and calculus (the latter defines `vx` in terms of `x`, etc.). There are two main forces on the ball:

1. Gravity, which has size `mg` and points straight down.
2. Air resistance, also called drag, which points opposite to the current direction. The magnitude is tricky. There are [multiple formulas for drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)). The one or ones you choose depend on the complexity of your simulation.

Also depending on the complexity of your simulation, you may want to consider the spin on the ball, which changes the drag, and so on. But those two are the minimum for what you wrote.

Then use an ODE (Ordinary Differential Equation) solver to simulate the positions and velocities of the ball. There are many, but one that is very good and fairly simple is [RK4, the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method). This is simple enough that you could program it yourself, but there are many packages that can do it. A popular function is [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)
 in the `scipy` package, which can do a variety of methods.

If you do not understand ODE solvers, you really should not be doing this kind of project. The skills you mention seem irrelevant to this project. If you remove the "in air" part of your requirements there are simpler simulations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time sir. There are tons of people out there who are just busy downvoting. I bet, you must be teaching keen and ardent students.

Comment: I used kalman filters before. Got stucked in some problem, as I've mentioned and could not find a way out by myself. I posted my code here too but got no replies. So I thought I must start over once again.

Comment: I was thinking about using euler's method to trace the trajectory since you need an initial starting point(it is provided by my tracking algorithm) and the differential equation of the curve to actually trace it. (right ?) I am not assuming any sort of air drag, just acceleration due to gravity. I am comfortable with ODE's on paper only, but know nothing about how to program them. So I think I should join some course    like this: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs222

Comment: Is this the correct direction, sir? Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: If you leave out air drag, then your problem statement is misleading ("in air"). This is also then easily solved with pure math and high-school physics: the ball's path is a parabola. Euler's method is suitable only if you want to be very simple and you don't care about the accuracy of the results. Euler's method today is considered for teaching only as an introduction to numerical ODE solving, not suitable for actual use. RK4 is used far more often and is not much more complicated.

Comment: "In air" just meant that the ball is somewhere high above ground and I just need to predict how it would come down due to the effect of gravity alone, much like any basic high-school problem. So ultimately, I need to learn how to play with ODEs in python, right ?

Comment: It's very generous of Rory Daulton to lead you down the path, but you need to make more of an effort here, Rahul.  This is one of the first chapters in an elementary physics text.  Ordinary differential equations are certainly beyond introductory calculus.  Euler integration would be good enough, now that we have computers where the small timesteps required for stability are not a hardship.